# JavaFX - Using for loops in GridPane?

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, gridpane

I am trying to use two for loops to automatically add ImageView nodes to each location. When using the for loops I receive an error. When I comment the for loop code out with only one statement to add an ImageView node the code seems to work can you use for loops to populate GridPane? If so what am I doing wrong? If not what could be used as a solution?

My Class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GridCreation extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage gameStage) throws Exception {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Image backOfCardsImg = new Image("images/naruto_shipuden_logo.png");
    ImageView backOfCards = new ImageView(backOfCardsImg);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                grid.add(backOfCards, i, j);

            }
        }

    //grid.add(backOfCards, 1,1);
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
    gameStage.setTitle("MemoryGame");
    gameStage.setScene(scene);
    gameStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Edit: for the code:

```
grid.add(backOfCards, i, j);
```

I changed the line of code to

```
grid.add(new ImageView(backOfCardImg), i, j);
```

this seemed to solve the problem but can anyone explain to me why the first option wouldnt work?

Comment: `ImageView` is a `Node`, and you can't reuse it, or you will get this exception: `Children: duplicate children added`. The second solution works because you create one new imageview for every cell on the grid.

Comment: I want to reuse the image and add it to each gridPane is their any solution to this?

Comment: As a FX node can only have on parent and isonly allowed to be added once to that parent, you have to create a new ImageView() for each time you want to shoaw that image in your grid. It will not duplicate th eimage itself, only the JavaFX container/control for the view.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a usable start for a memory game in fx. It uses an own extension of ImageView to do the turn and focus animations and to deal with a common backside image. Its only graphics, no game logic.

```
public class MemoryGame extends Application {
    final int rows = 4;
    final int columns = 4;
    CardView views[][] = new CardView[rows][];

    public static class CardView extends ImageView {
        static final double scale = 0.95;
        static DropShadow shadowhoover = new DropShadow(5, 4, 4, Color.rgb(50, 60, 50));
        static DropShadow shadowdown = new DropShadow(2, 2, 2, Color.rgb(50, 60, 50));
        static Image backside = null;
        public static void setbackside(Image image) { backside = image; }

        public CardView(Image image) { 
            super(backside); 
            setRotationAxis(new Point3D(0, 200,0));
            setScaleX(scale);
            setScaleY(scale);
            setEffect(shadowdown);
            setOnMouseEntered(m -> {
                setEffect(shadowhoover);
                setScaleX(scale*1.01);
                setScaleY(scale*1.01);
            });
            setOnMouseExited(m -> {
                setEffect(shadowdown);
                setScaleX(scale);
                setScaleY(scale);
            });
            setOnMouseClicked(m -> {      
                RotateTransition r1 = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(300), this);
                r1.setByAngle(90);
                r1.setOnFinished(e -> setImage(image));
                RotateTransition r2 = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(300), this);
                r2.setByAngle(-90);

                RotateTransition r3 = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(300), this);
                r3.setByAngle(90);
                r3.setOnFinished(e -> setImage(backside));
                RotateTransition r4 = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(300), this);
                r4.setByAngle(-90);

                new SequentialTransition(r1, r2, new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(1000)), r3, r4).play();
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage gameStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.rgb(140, 200, 140), new CornerRadii(0), new Insets(0))));
        grid.setHgap(5);
        grid.setVgap(5);
        Image back = new Image(MemoryGame.class.getResource("card-back.png").toExternalForm(), 140, 200, true, true);
        Image front = new Image(MemoryGame.class.getResource("card-1.png").toExternalForm(), 140, 200, true, true);
        CardView.setbackside(back);
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            views[r] = new CardView[columns];
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                CardView view = new CardView(front); // different front images of course...
                views[r][c] = view;

                HBox box = new HBox(5);
                box.getChildren().add(views[r][c]);
                grid.add(box, c, r);

            }
        }

        //grid.add(backOfCards, 1,1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
        gameStage.setTitle("MemoryGame");
        gameStage.setScene(scene);
        gameStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```